# .htaccess caching with FilesMatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I need to make browser caching with htaccess file.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724549/caching-and-gzip-compression-by-htaccess/6724556#6724556) I found out how to add extensions to htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|jpeg|jpg)$">
```

But I need to add extensions. But exclude some of the files.
I found something like this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182936/htaccess-deny-access-to-specific-files-more-than-one/2183013#2183013)

```
<FilesMatch ^((myfile|myfile2)\.js$|myphoto\.jpe?g)$>
```

Add all js and jpeg files except "myfile.js", "myfile2.js", "myphoto.jpg"
How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<FilesMatch "((?<!myfile|myfile2)\.js|(?<!myphoto).jpe?g)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

This will match all `js` and `jpeg` files except `myfile.js`, `myfile2.js`, and `myphoto.jpeg` using negative lookahead/lookbehind. Kind of ugly but I couldn't find a nice way to do this.

You can then have a separate files match for *only* those files and set a different header:

```
<FilesMatch "((myfile|myfile2)\.js|myphoto\.jpe?g)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public" 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I wrote following code    `<FilesMatch "\.(js|jpe?g)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"  
</FilesMatch>  
  
<FilesMatch "^((myfile|myfile2)\.js|myphoto\.jpe?g)$">  
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"  
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: But "myfile.js" has following header response. There exists 2 Cache-Control variables in header..         **Cache-Control:max-age=604800**
    **Cache-Control:max-age=3600, public**