# inverted FilesMatch?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm setting cache control headers for files. I want to set `max-age=86400` for all `.css` and `.js`, and `max-age=3600` for all others.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header append Cache-Control max-age=86400
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "???">
    Header append Cache-Control max-age=3600
</FilesMatch>
```

I can't figure out what regex I should write to invert `\.(css|js)$` match. Or maybe there is some other way to do this?

**UPDATE**. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115652/htaccess-caching-with-filesmatch) answer I've found solution that works:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.css|\.js)$">
    Header append Cache-Control max-age=3600
</FilesMatch>
```

Unfortunatelly can't find a way to leave dot `\.` outside of brackets. But still this solution fine for me.

As a side note, *all other files* include ones with not filename at all, like `http://example.com/`.

Comment: doesn't `(?<!\.(css|js))$` work? It is a variable length lookbehind, so in some languages doesn't work, however also leaving the dot like this is fine.

Comment: Nope, tried that in the first place, but Apache throws regex compilation exception for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115652/htaccess-caching-with-filesmatch) answer I've found solution that works:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.css|\.js)$">
    Header append Cache-Control max-age=3600
</FilesMatch>
```

Unfortunatelly can't find a way to leave dot `\.` outside of brackets. But still this solution fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should go check to the end of the string for the real file extension (which is the last, non dot-containing substring)

```
.+\.(?!(css|js)$)[^\.]+?$
```

Explanation:

- `.+\.` Search greedily the whole string to find the last dot.
- `(?!(css|js)$)` skip any `.css` or `.js` terminating to the end of the line (but keep for example `.jsx`)
- `[^\.]+?$` get the extension part (no dots until the end of the string)

Comment: See updated question, seems like I've found working solution. However, I appreciate your efforts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
.+?\.(?!(css$|js$)).+
```

The first group `.+?` gets the file name and the second negative look ahead group `?!(css$|js$)` checks to see that the file ending is not css or js. This matches only files which don't have .css or .js extensions. You can replace the first and the last . with character class based on the filename characters permitted.

Edited: This will match test.cssx or test.jxabc

Comment: What about `test.cssx`? Should be matched but it isn't

Comment: You are right, it was wrong. Deleted my comment. Your solution works correctly and considers all edge cases.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to seem a bully, just wanted to point you in the correct direction, the problem is that the `.+?\.` matches the first dot not followed by `css$`, this means that if the `css` substring is after a dot and before the extension the string will look OK. This is resolved telling the regex "in the extension part I don't want dots" thus writing `[^\.]+$` instead of `.+`

Comment: See updated question, seems like I've found working solution. However, I appreciate your efforts anyway.